# Extracting LINQ select expression out

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a LINQ chained query which looks like this

```
return incidents
    .Include(x => x.Submission)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Answer)
    .Select(incident => new Incident
    {
        Id = incident.Id,
        Submission = incident.Submission.Select(submission => new Submission
        {
            Id = submission.Id,
            Answer = context.SubFields.ContainsKey("answer") ? submission.Answer : null
        }).ToList()
```

`incidents` is of type `IQueryable<Incident>` and I am trying to select particular fields so the SQL query generated when we hit the database doesn't select every single property, some of which we don't need and are making the query slow. The ternary expression determines if we actually need that particular property selected from the DB (this comes from a GraphQL query so we don't know ahead of time). This code all works at the moment and generates the most optimal SQL query.

What I want to do is extract the lambda expression from within the `Submission`'s select method out into a separate method. As we will be using `Submission` beyond this `Incident` query, I want to extract it to a method which I can reuse.

In an ideal world, I am trying to get my code to look like the following, but I don't know how to do the expression generation. How do I do this?

```
Submission =  incident.Submission.Select(GENERATE_AN_EXPRESSION(context.SubFields["submission"])).ToList()
```

```
GENERATE_AN_EXPRESSION(Field field)
        {
            return submission => new ApplicationCore.Entities.Submission
            {
                Id = submission.Id,
                Answer = submission.Answer.SelectAnswer(field.SelectionSet.GetField("answer"))
            };
        }
```

Comment: If you extract it to a different method, linq-to-entities might not be able to create a sql query out of it

Comment: Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries#example). In general its a bit pita to build expression trees. Also helpful: [Dixin's Blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/functional-csharp-function-as-data-and-expression-tree)

Comment: Since Expression Trees are immutable you gotta start from the leafs and work up the tree till the root (usually a `LambdaExpression`)